# How do you use a non-number as a seed in an RNG?

Tags: random

How would you use, say, the string `"abc"` as the seed of an RNG? Would you change it into `0x616263`, or `123`, or hash it with sha1 (or some other hash), or something else?

Comment: Why would you want to use a string as a seed? and if your end result is a random number, does it really matter how you represent it as a number?

Comment: TTG: If you want to use user input to seed your RNG, it will quite likely be a string.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing with a high-quality hashing algorithm seems like the best solution. However, depending on how many bits you have to seed with, you might have to use only a part of the generated hash. This shouldn't be a problem if you use a cryptographically strong algorithm that has well-distributed outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming

- you want a repeatable pseudorandom
  sequence
- your RNG expects an integer.

In this case, the answer is: it doesn't matter.